# Trying to disable button in all pages in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Datatables JQuery plugin in order to show data on a table.
In one of the columns I have added also a button to edit the rows.
What I am trying to do is when I click one of the buttons, to deactivate all the others.

Here is my current code together with a screenshot:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "._edit_save_btn",function(e){
   var id = this.id; // get id of selected btn
  // disable all other buttons but selected
  $("._edit_save_btn").not("#"+id).prop('disabled', true);
```

)};

[image]

Although this works fine for the first page of data (paginated presentation), when I change page, it seems like that the property disabled is not applied.
Thus I can click any other button in order to add the property disabled.

I thought by using the on click event things would work. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

The table is created automatically using DataTables jquery plugin and jquery functionality.
On page load my html structure looks like this:

```
<table id="example">
  <thead id="table_head">
  </thead>
</table>
```

Then the table is populated with data coming from Django. The button element looks like this:

```
edit_btn = '<button id="' + row_id + '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm _edit_save_btn" style="background-color:#a7a3a3;border-color:#a7a3a3">Edit</button>'
```

**EDIT_2**

This screenshot explains better what I mean with pagination and changing pages. Please check the lower right corner to see the pagination. When I go to another page (e.g. from 1 to 2) then I see that the disabled property wasnot applied for the buttons on that page:

[image]

**EDIT**

With the help of @Sherin Jose I have managed to reach to this point:

```
var disable_buttons = function(class_exists){
  if (class_exists){
    alert("dfdf")
    $("._edit_save_btn").not(this).prop('disabled', true);
  }
};


  $("#example").dataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "aaData":whole_array
  }).on( 'page.dt', function () {
    class_exists = $("button").hasClass("clicked");
    //alert(class_exists)
    disable_buttons(class_exists)
  });
```

Whenever a user clicks a button, then the button gets a class called clicked.
Then in the disable_buttons function, I check if this class exists (the 'clicked' class). If it exists I want to disable the other buttons on page change event.

The issue I am facing now is that the

```
 on( 'page.dt', function () {
```

is executed before the datatable is loaded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
//define the disable feature as a function
var disable_buttons = function(){
    $("._edit_save_btn").unbind("click").click(function(e){
        // disable all other buttons but selected
        $("._edit_save_btn").not(this).prop('disabled', true);  
    });
};


//call the above function on dataTable init and page change events like:
$("#example").dataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "aaData":whole_array,
    "fnDrawCallback":function () {
        disable_buttons();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure where I should add the second part. This is how I initialize my datatable: $("#example").dataTable({
      "scrollX": true,
      "aaData":whole_array
    });

Comment: I think we are missing something. It seems like the disable_buttons function is never called. I tried to alert something inside it but never gets executed.

Comment: I think this line is messing things up: $("._edit_save_btn").unbind("click").click(function(e){

Comment: I have edited it again with `drawCallback`. try it now

Comment: Ok. So now it works as at the very beginning. I think your approach using an event  ('page.dt') is the way to go.

Comment: Do the `disable_buttons()` function is working now ?

Comment: Yeah. drawCallback doesn't give the desired result. Its a tricky issue.

Comment: Replaced `drawCallback` with `fnDrawCallback`.. Now it will help you